# POST Details for Strapi Relations

Tags: strapi

I've got a simple data model, which has a tag and that is linked to an upload:

```
    Tag Table                  Upload Table
    id                         id
    name                       tag_id
                               title
```

Now, trying to save an item to the upload, I expected the JSON to be:

```
{
    "title": "Testing",
    "tag_id": {"id": 1}
}
```

But this never works or links. What am I doing wrong?